# Azure active directory authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Webforms web application built on framework 4.0, currently it was using local AD authentication. Now the application is deployed to Azure.We have requirement for Azure active directory authentication .

I am new to Azure. Please let me know the steps for Azure AD authentication.
What are the configuration needs to be done & code changes.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

This article walks you through on how to setup Azure AD authentication for your (App service) web application - [Configure Azure AD authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/)

Additionally you might want to consider syncing your on-premise directories with Azure AD using Azure AD Connect. More about that here - [Integrating on-premise identities with Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/).